# How to change user input in FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I'm using FormFlow in bot framework. What is the best way to store the user's input differently after he answers a question?

For instance, I would like to ask "What is your name" and then store only the first word before the next whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Validate can be used for that purpose (see [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html), "Adding Business Logic" section)

Here's an example of how I did it:

```
.Field(nameof(ClusterName), validate: (state, value) => Task.FromResult(new ValidateResult
                {
                    Value = state.GetFirstName((string)value),
                    IsValid = true
                }))
```